# Error: Owner Doesn't exist?

Tags: apex, soql, community

**Apex Class:**

```
public static String getOpportunityName(){

       String communityUserEmail = [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()].email;
       List<Id> oppIds = new List<Id>();

       List<Contact> conts = [select name,(select name,ownerId from Opportunities) from Contact where Email = :communityUserEmail];
         for(Contact c : conts)
         for(Opportunity cts : c.opportunities){   

               oppIds.add(cts.ownerId);      
     }
     List<Opportunity>  ct = [select name,Ownerid from Opportunity 
      where id = :oppIds ];
      return ct.owner.name; //HERE SHOWS THE ERROR CALLED Variable DOESN'T OWNER
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Error is Here**
>
> List  ct = [select name,Ownerid from Opportunity 
>     where id = :oppIds ];
>
> return ct.owner.name; //HERE SHOWS THE ERROR CALLED Variable DOESN'T OWNER

Because of the wrong SOQL and return statement is list of Opportunity, & your trying to access directly without an index value.

```
List<Opportunity>  ct = [select Name,Owner.name from Opportunity where id = :oppIds ];
 return ct[0].owner.name;
```

**or**

```
 Opportunity  ct = [select Name,Owner.name from Opportunity where id = :oppIds limit 1];
     return ct.owner.name;
```

Comment: tq nithesh the error resolved

Comment: @Raj Welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you should consider, besides the **error**, as part of [apex best-practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) guidelines

> 1. Don't need to SOQL to get current user email address

```
String communityUserEmail = [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()].email;
```

You don't need to perform SOQL here, as there is a direct method to get the current user's email using `Userinfo.getUserEmail()`, so optimized version of your statement would be

`String communityUserEmail = Userinfo.getUserEmail();`

> 2. Use `SOQL-for-loops` - which is scalable and more efficient (refer to the best practices article for details)

```
List<Contact> conts = [select name,(select name,ownerId from Opportunities) from Contact where Email = :communityUserEmail];
     for(Contact c : conts)
```

**Better approach**

```
for(Contact c : [select name,(select name,ownerId from Opportunities) from Contact where Email = :communityUserEmail])
```

> 3. What if your current user has no opportunities, means `oppIds` is null? Put a check to avoid [null-pointer exception](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000063739&type=1)

**improved version**

```
if (oppIds.size() > 0) List<Opportunity>  ct = [select name,Ownerid from Opportunity  where id = :oppIds ];
```